# ActiveRecord metaprogramming in a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rubygems

So I have to activerecord classes in a gem:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  Role.all.each do |role|
    class_eval <<-CODE
      def #{role.name}?
        # code to determin presence of role
      end
    CODE
  end
end
```

This makes various admin? style methods in user based on the roles that actually exist.

However, this is causing some problems because when the gem is included in a project, it's trying to query Role before ActiveRecord has established a connection, resulting in an exception being thrown. I can simply move the metaprogramming to an initializer or something, but then it has to be repeated in every application that uses the gem. Is there any other way to defer this until Rails has finished setting up?

Comment: I doubt the error would be Role class not loaded yet instead of no connection. Can you post the errors?

Comment: The error is ActiveRecord ConnectionNotEstablish

Comment: Got it. For me it's hard to debug without actual code in hand. However it looks the gem is still very simple at present, have you tried to put the Role class inside 'app/models' but not as a gem and does that work?